# Copy width/height from one rectangle to others? (Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have several rectangles, all of which are slightly different sizes, I want to make them all the same height/width as the top one.

Running the latest illustrator CC 2015.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just rectangles (or other primitive shapes) then you can use the following method:

Select all of your rectangles and then enter a width and height in the 'shape' dimension boxes at the top of the screen (your toolbar visibility might need changing for it to look like my screenshots). Obviously, you'll need to get the target size from the relevant box in your document so that you can apply it to the others.

Before:[image]
After:[image]